# IFS does not work on older versions of Excel

Tags: excel, formula, ifs

My IFS formula works on my Excel 365 but no on other lower version of Excel. Is there any alternative for this to do older way?

```
=IFS(AND(B9>=Period!$F$6,B9<=Period!$G$6),Period!$E$6,AND(B9>=Period!$F$7,B9<=Period!$G$7),Period!$E$7,AND(B9>=Period!$F$8,B9<=Period!$G$8),Period!$E$8,AND(B9>=Period!$F$9,B9<=Period!$G$9),Period!$E$9,AND(B9>=Period!$F$10,B9<=Period!$G$10),Period!$E$10,AND(B9>=Period!$F$11,B9<=Period!$G$11),Period!$E$11,AND(B9>=Period!$F$12,B9<=Period!$G$12),Period!$E$12,AND(B9>=Period!$F$13,B9<=Period!$G$13),Period!$E$13,AND(B9>=Period!$F$14,B9<=Period!$G$14),Period!$E$14,AND(B9>=Period!$F$15,B9<=Period!$G$15),Period!$E$15,AND(B9>=Period!$F$16,B9<=Period!$G$16),Period!$E$16,AND(B9>=Period!$F$17,B9<=Period!$G$17),Period!$E$17,AND(B9>=Period!$F$18,B9<=Period!$G$18),Period!$E$18,AND(B9>=Period!$F$19,B9<=Period!$G$19),Period!$E$19,AND(B9>=Period!$F$20,B9<=Period!$G$20),Period!$E$20)
```

Comment: Some sample data may help?

Comment: Expected result (working in Excel 365) is --> http://prntscr.com/pb3xoz
Period table --> http://prntscr.com/pb3ysd
IFS doesnt work in older version of Excel --> http://prntscr.com/pb3yfj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `VLOOKUP` function with `True` as the third argument.

[image]

You can also combine `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions.  Set `1` as the the third argument in `MATCH` function.

[image]

Comment: Vlookup works pretty well for me.....quite simple!
Wonder what made me think so hard way to use IFS instead!? :O

Comment: @DeveloperOEA  `VLOOKUP` is more powerful than you think.  If my answer help you, please accept my answer.

Comment: Yes! I accepted you answer unless I need to click anywhere

Comment: @DeveloperOEA There is a gray check mark.  Click that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this one:
=INDEX($E$6:$E$20,MATCH(1,COUNTIFS(B9,"<="&$G$6:$G$20,B9,">="&$F$6:$F$20),0))
and then click Ctrl+Shift+Enter at same time.

*however any sample data would be much better